# Which partition should I install the bootloader on?

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader

I am about to install Ubuntu 10.10 on my Windows 7 system

I will be dual booting with Windows 7 and want to use Windows 7 as my default OS for now. Where should I put the bootloader/GRUB; on the Windows partition or the root partition of Ubuntu? I have read elsewhere that Windows 7 tends to corrupt grub2.

Also, is there a way to use Windows 7's bootloader instead of selecting the OS from grub? I don't know much about bootloaders.

Answer (score 3):

Have a good read through the Community Documentation here;

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

GRUB needs to be installed into the Master Boot Record of your hard drive and it will detect Win7 and automatically include it as a boot option.

Answer (score 0):

Install the grub2 bootloader to your hard drive's root partition, which is the default.

Linux supports booting Windows better than Windows supports booting Linux so I recommend using grub as the primary boot loader and not the Windows boot loader.

You likely won't have any problems with Windows corrupting grub2 as long as Windows was installed before Ubuntu.

To set Windows as the default boot choice, see [How do I make Windows 7 the default OS instead of ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7865/1579) especially the answer from sroecker.

Comment: It's Windows Boot Manager, not Windows boot loader(which is called by WBM).