# Windows Boot Manager: Make Ubuntu the default instead of Windows

Tags: wubi

When I boot my computer, I get the Windows Boot Manager with Vista selected and Ubuntu as the other item in the list.

If I choose Ubuntu, I get the GRUB menu. I have updated GRUB menus before so I know how that works, but since Windows Boot Manager comes first, I don't know how to change the default.

I looked at this question: [How do I make Windows 7 the default OS instead of ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7865/how-do-i-make-windows-7-the-default-os-instead-of-ubuntu)
But it seems that that uses GRUB, but the default I want to change is before GRUB even comes up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so I found the answer almost immediately: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/easily-set-default-os-in-a-windows-vista-and-xp-dual-boot-setup/

> 1. Boot to Windows
> 2. right click on Computer and select Properties
> 3. click Advanced System Settings
> 4. click on the Settings button under Startup and Recovery
> 5. select the operating system you want to use
>
> Easy stuff. You could also use the [bcdedit command](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/set-xp-as-the-default-os-in-a-windows-vista-dual-boot-setup/) to do the same thing from the command line, but it’s probably easier this way.

#### Warning:

After doing this, you will not be able to boot Windows again if the timeout is set to zero seconds, without repairing the boot-loader using a repair disc. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/245099/2355).

Answer (score 3):

You can use EasyBCD, a gui application, to do it.

Examples with screenshots [here](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/01/28/dual-booting-windows-7-and-ubuntu-10-10/2/).