# How can I boot into Windows after I set Ubuntu as the default operating system? (I'm using Wubi)

Tags: boot, windows, wubi

I followed [this guide here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43017/windows-boot-manager-make-ubuntu-the-default-instead-of-windows) to set the default operating system at boot-up to Ubuntu. Since I installed Ubuntu using Wubi, it involved setting the default operating system of the Windows boot-looader using some preference settings on Windows.

Now I have locked myself out of booting into Windows at all. I cannot use F12, F8 or anything to get Windows to boot.

Does anyone have a guide to boot into Windows so I can change the option back to choose what operating system I want to boot?

Answer (score 3):

Because you've installed Ubuntu using Wubi, you need to modify the settings of Windows boot loader, not GRUB.

Grab a Windows repair DVD. Boot from it, and select the option to open a DOS command-line. Type this:

```
bcdedit /timeout 10
```

This will change the time out of the Windows' bootloader to ten seconds, giving you enough time to select Windows.

Once you've booted Windows, you can change the default back to Windows, in the same [way that you had originally changed the default to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/43018/2355):

1. Right click on Computer and select Properties
2. Click Advanced System Settings
3. Click on the Settings button under Startup and Recovery
4. Select Windows.

#### Reference:

- [This Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1943672)

Answer (score 0):

you can repair windows bootloader and reset settings

boot from windows livecd/repair your comupter

click on command promot :

```
bcdedit /timeout 10
```

[more information here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/)

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a good windows live cd? I prefer a free one.

Comment: I am a complete noob who is overly frustrated. I JUST WANT TO BOOT WINDOWS. When i download these windows reapir live CDs they want to open a .exe file and build one. IS THERE A WAY TO MAKE THIS FROM UBUNTU? anyone got something?

Comment: here free tool , check it please 

[pebuilder](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/#download)