# How to make Ubuntu the default OS?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a machine in which I had Windows 10 before installing Ubuntu 16 recently. But each time I start the computer, if I am not close to enter into the boot setup to specify Ubuntu, it goes straight on Windows. I would like that the default OS selected is Ubuntu.

I tried to edit my grub order by doing this: `sudo gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, but I had already this line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`, indicating my Ubuntu should be the first to boot.

I guess my Ubuntu is using UEFI since I have the following folder: `/sys/firmware/efi/`.

This question has already an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager?answertab=active#tab-top).

But this answer is very old now. And I wonder if there is a new way to solve the same issue, using only Ubuntu. If not, I would like to know why should we use only Windows to solve the issue.

Comment: does your EFI setting allow OS selection under boot order?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Could you explain, please?

Comment: sett your perminate boot oreder in the system settings.

Comment: I edited my question. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Boot Manager: Make Ubuntu the default instead of Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43017/windows-boot-manager-make-ubuntu-the-default-instead-of-windows)

Comment: Are you arriving at the grub menu? Then `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` *should* work. But there is a second step: You must make it active by running `sudo update-grub`. If it is still not working, booting is not using this grub menu, but some other grub menu or other boot menu. If BIOS mode you may have to run `sudo grub-install  /dev/sdx` where x is the drive that the computer is booting from. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2 ; If UEFI mode (with factory installed Windows 10), see the link to the original question (of which yours may be a duplicate).

Comment: @edkeveked -- no it doesn't. go into the system setting and change the boot order.

Comment: @sudodus -- as I read it, is booting the windows boot manager not grub. He needs to set grub as first in the system boot order

Comment: @ravery, I am not sure but would guess it is the UEFI case (which would mean it is a duplicate as suggested by George). If Ubuntu was installed after Windows, it should be able to grab the booting into its grub menu. But obviously it does not work in this case. I think and hope that is can be fixed by the method we are referring to.

Comment: @sudodus -- I have seen some systems ignore the EFI NVRAM settings if it has OS boot selection in the EFI firmware.

Comment: Yes @ravery , you are right. There are many different cases. Some UEFI systems are difficult to manage, some are easier; some are special cases, some comply with the UEFI standard.

Comment: @George, the link you provided did not solve the issue for me. Only my Windows appears in the options to select.

Comment: @sudodus, what you suggested is the only thing that works for me. Could you post it as an answer and I will accept it? I guess, that this question is different from the previous ones and that it should not be considered as a duplicate one. Am I wrong?

Comment: You have tested in your computer, and now you know more than we know :-) We suggested things based on experiences from other computers. I will make the method via grub into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2)

`GRUB_DEFAULT=0` *should* work, if you are arriving at Ubuntu's grub menu. But there is a second step: You must make it active by running

```
sudo update-grub
```

If it is still not working, booting is not using this grub menu, but some other grub menu or other boot menu.

You may have to run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdx
```

where x is the drive that the computer is booting from. See this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB‌​_2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2)

Comment: `GRUB_DEFAULT=0 ` and `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` didn't work for me. here's how my boot menu looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiyfM.jpg

Comment: @NaveenKumar, Am I understanding correctly, that your computer does not boot via grub by default, that you must go via the temporary boot menu to get to grub (and its menu)? Otherwise (by default) it boots directly into Windows? -- What computer is it (brand name and model)? Can you go into the computer's UEFI/BIOS setup menus and see if there is a way to change the boot order (between Windows Boot manager and Ubuntu)? -- I think you have a different problem (from the one in this thread), so you should 'ask a separate new question'. You can link to it from a comment here if you wish.

Comment: yes, my computer boots directly into windows 10, if i don't interrupt the boot process and choose to boot into Ubuntu. I am using a laptop, hp-bs 145tu with core-15 8250U, 8GB RAM and no dedicated GPU. I have tried basically everything to change default os(from ubuntu), but go into UEFI. I will do that right now.

Comment: thanks for the advice. changing the boot order in bios settings helped. and ubuntu is my default os now.

Comment: You are welcome @NaveenKumar :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43017/windows-boot-manager-make-ubuntu-the-default-instead-of-windows).

The solution is as follows.

> 1. Boot to Windows
> 2. right click on Computer and select Properties
> 3. click Advanced System Settings
> 4. click on the Settings button under Startup and Recovery
> 5. select the operating system you want to use

**Warning:**

After doing this, you will not be able to boot Windows again if the timeout is set to zero seconds, without repairing the boot-loader using a repair disc.

Comment: windows does not see linux installs. I'm not sure how much this effects EFI systems, as technically is should be able to see grubs loader but may ignore it

Comment: It did not solve the issue for me. As a matter of fact, only my Windows appears in the options I have to select (at the 5th step).

Comment: doesnt work, ubuntu doesnt show in the options inside windows 10