# Get Back Ubuntu's GRUB menu with Ubuntu first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

#### Initial setup working: Ubuntu and Windows

My laptop had two OS working:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 and
2. Windows 8.1

At boot it showed "GNU GRUB Version 2.02 by Ubuntu."

#### Current setup, not satisfying

I recently installed Linux mint 18.2 cinnamon on it.
Now at boot it shows `GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.9+linuxmint1` and Linux Mint first:

[image: photo]

#### Desired setup: Ubuntu first, Ubuntu GRUB style

I'd like Ubuntu 14.04 at the first position, Linuxmint, and Windows after that. Also, I'd like GRUB with the Ubuntu style with Magenta background color.

As said in comment, I've deleted Linux Mint and don't know how to get Ubuntu first in list.

Comment: Post this: `sudo efibootmgr -v`, if Mint not using 'ubuntu'. If UEFI boot which it should be with any Windows 8 pre-installed system. You just need to change default UEFI boot order. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr Also review `man efibootmgr` In past Mint has used "ubuntu" entry. Then you need to edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. But you could also boot into Ubuntu and just totally reinstall grub which will update entry. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220

Comment: No, First I installed Ubuntu then go for a Windows one year later.

Comment: Each OS installing GRUB tends to put itself first on the list. Can you try this: boot to Ubuntu 14.04, login (first account created on the machine should do) and there run `sudo update-grub` then reboot. If that fits what you want, I'll make that comment an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) GRUB Customizer should do the job.

Comment: Unfortunately I deleted linuxmint mint but still the option appears on grub menu..( like the picture above)

Comment: Doing `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu should remove it. @StéphaneGourichon That is the answer indeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Ubuntu the default OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964893/how-to-make-ubuntu-the-default-os)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found an answer yet.

Looks like you only have 1 hard drive `/dev/sda`, right?  If that is the case, boot to Ubuntu, from the terminal type in:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

That should override the GRUB that was installed by Mint.  Then you will have to update the GRUB again:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps!