# How to force grub to boot only the 1st OS?

Tags: boot, grub2

Good evening,

I'm running the lastest ubuntu server edition (i like the: apt-get update/upgrade ; command... a lot) and i need grub to boot only the 1st Ubuntu Server Image (every time).

The grub menu displays: 2 server images and 1 memory tests and 1 extra os *from a second attached hdd*

These 4 can be found listed in /boot/grub/grub.cfg (i m thinking of deleting the other entries but i ve read that the .cfg file is generated automatically if i add/remove kernel)

Can i set a **GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true** command in the /etc/default/grub ? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB2 
Or does that not apply to my configuration ?

PS. I think grub pops up because i have often power losses, but i still want grub to load the ubuntu OS... since it s sole purpose is to be a server and local access is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never edit your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file - this is always regenerated when a new kernel is downloaded and installed.

If your Ubuntu OS is always the first in the list then the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in `/etc/default/grub` is sufficient for this to be the first OS to be booted on a restart.

If your Ubuntu OS is not the first then you can set the `GRUB_DEFAULT` value to be equal to the menu entry value for Ubuntu OS - see the linked answer below on an example of how to find the OS value and how to add it to Grub.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990)

Comment: edited the /etc/default/grub with Grub_Default='Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-11-server' ... and rebooted... all went well...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that will help you:

[Grub 2 Guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)

If your system had a Graphical User Interface then I would recommend Grub Customizer. Here is a link for completeness:

[Grub Customizer for easy editing of Grub](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)

Regards.