# Can't login after power outage

Tags: boot, login-screen

I have a desktop with no battery power with a very simple surge protector.  I am running Ubuntu 64-bit 12.04. Apt-get needed a restart of my computer to finish installing the latest updates I had downloaded. Before I was able to do that, the power went out.  Now when I boot up, all I see is a black screen after I select Ubuntu in the grub menu.  I am able to get to the recovery options from the grub screen. I tried loading the failsafex version but that also failed.  I have never posted anything to a forum before but I have to get this working ASAP because of a work project due for a client.  I'll be up all night until I can get this fixed.  Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is that a kernel upgrade is causing the problem. From the grub menu instead of selecting recovery mode, boot using the older kernel version. If it works then set that kernel as the default. Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68547/editing-the-default-boot-item-in-grub-menu-a-definitive-answer) to set the default kernel.

Comment: I get the same result unfortunately.  I have tried 3 of the previous versions so far all with the same result.  When I am stuck at the black screen, I am able to do ctrl-alt-f1 then ctrl-alt-delete to reboot. I sadly never see the terminal when I hit ctrl-alt-f1.

Comment: If you can't even login to the console I don't think there's much you can do. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/ubuntu-11-10-black-screen-after-boot-screen-908044/ is similar to your problem, but if you can't get any access I'm not sure how to solve this. Sorry to be preachy, but this is the exact reason why you shouldn't make changes to your stable system if you have a deadline due.