# mei_me initialization failed at boot up

Tags: boot, kernel

I have an "mei_me" error at system boot-up.

```
May  2 17:47:39 florian-Linux kernel: [   11.867542] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X
May  2 17:47:39 florian-Linux kernel: [   11.870423] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: version message write failed: ret = -5
May  2 17:47:39 florian-Linux kernel: [   11.870452] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: hbm_start failed ret = -5
May  2 17:47:39 florian-Linux kernel: [   11.870470] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: reset failed
May  2 17:47:39 florian-Linux kernel: [   11.870487] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: link layer initialization failed.
May  2 17:47:39 florian-Linux kernel: [   11.870509] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: init hw failure.
May  2 17:47:39 florian-Linux kernel: [   11.891233] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: initialization failed.
```

My Kernel version:

```
3.13.0-51-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 12:08:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

can anyone say me: where come this error from and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try adding the line`blacklist mei` to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`?

Comment: No I don't try this, but I think this should work and causes in no errors at the bootup. But I don't know for what I need the mei_me service... Also this don't solve the problem, only the logs ;)

Comment: More about [Intel mei](http://forums.tweaktown.com/gigabyte/55149-intel-management-engine-interface-needed.html). I've seen few people were able to solve the issue by blacklisting (or even doing `rmmod`)

Comment: Ron: Thanks for your help... I try to boot with an older kernel(xx0-49), and there the problem doesn't exist. My Problem now: How to tell grub to boot with the older kernel every bootup?

Comment: which kernal are you using? (the output of `uname -a`)

Comment: see the post;) the kernel it does not work : 3.13.0-51; the kernel it does work 3.13.0-49

Comment: yeah, i meant the one which works :P

Comment: Relevant bug in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1450813

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell grub to use older kernal everytime you can refer to the official [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) or this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68547/editing-the-default-boot-item-in-grub-menu-a-definitive-answer). In short, you need to change the value of `GRUB_DEFAULT` in the file `/etc/default/grub`. To know what value you should put in for `GRUB_DEFAULT`, you have to refer to the order of boot entries listed in the grub menu. This information comes from the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This basically involves counting the `menuentries` and matching it with the position of your old-kernal as listed in the grub menu.

Comment: Thanks, with xx0-49 Kernel it works without problems. Where I can report this "bug" with the kernel and the Ubuntu-version?

Comment: See [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), the official documentation to know more about bug reporting.