# mei_me timeout failure at boot up

Tags: boot, 18.04, bios

I have an `mei_me` error at system boot up with additional behavior， that **the computer'screen is refreshed about every 2 second**. After seeing `the purple boot screen of Ubuntu` I got these error (so I was not able to get the `login` screen so far):

```
    ...
    [ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
    [ OK ] Started Disk Manager
    [ OK ] Started Snappy daemon
    [ OK ] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
    [   34.079970] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: timer: init client timeouthbm_state = 2.
    [   94.560062] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: timer: init client timeouthbm_state = 2.
    [   94.561248] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: reset: reached maximal consecutive resets: disabling the device.
```

I got `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` with kernel version `4.15.0-43-generic`.

---

I already did some searching. With
[mei_me unexpected reset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419853/mei-me-unexpected-reset) and [mei_me initialization failed at boot up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617352/mei-me-initialization-failed-at-boot-up).

1. When I try to add `blacklist mei_me` at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file`, I was also not able to boot:

   ```
   ...
   [ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
   [ OK ] Started Disk Manager
   [ OK ] Started Snappy daemon
   [ OK ] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
   ```

I will be struck at the last line and make no progress. (Hmm the `mei_me` dosen't appear but it not so helpful for booting.)

2. When I try `control-p` to get to `Management Engine BIOS Extension Options`, it doesn't give me a reply and still lead me to the `Ubuntu OS`. But I was able to get to the BIOS with pressing `F2` and I got an Intel Core i5-4210. Maybe that is a way to fix my problem, when I could get to the `Management Engine BIOS Extension Options`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that is a **current issue** for the `18.04` and the solution that I found is this one: [18.04 Boot freezes at "Started Hold until boot process finishes up"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065094/18-04-boot-freezes-at-started-hold-until-boot-process-finishes-up).

I did have no space in the `/boot/` partition and I could boot to the OS, after I remote some old kernel image.
Seems this problem is not relevant to the `mei_me` but still hope this post could helpful for other having the same problem as me.