# Mouse and Keyboard not working in Linux Ubuntu 15.04/15.10 after update

Tags: 15.04, keyboard, mouse, 15.10, display-resolution

yesterday i installed some updates with the automatic ubuntu updater and shutdown my pc after that.

now i try to reboot and i now have the problem that my mouse and keyboard aren't recognized (not responding) anymore. besides that, the monitor has a very low resolution.

i have installed ubuntu 15.04 or 15.10, i cant remember exactly.

i already tried to remove all harddrives etc.

any help?

## UPDATE 1

- now i started the pc with holding shift and started with a older kernel (4.2.23-generic). it is running now as before.
- but how can i revert the update?

## UPDATE 2

- i now changed grub in that way, that it is automatically starting with the last kernel i found running (4.2.23-generic)
- to do that i followed the instructions in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68547/editing-the-default-boot-item-in-grub-menu-a-definitive-answer)
- [another link explaining how to change grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990)

## Links

- [Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Comment: Well, 15.04 has gone End-Of-Life and is no longer supported, so it would help if you could check which version you actually installed. It should be in the "Details" section of the System Settings.

Comment: Update your question to include the output of `cat /etc/os-release` as this will tell us what OS version you are running.  Thank you!

Comment: As for your mouse,keyboard thing , go to older kernel , like , before 4.0, maybe 3.13 if you have that. Use usb or wireless keyboard / mouse for now

Comment: It is also inadvisable to only run an old kernel because it will not be patched with new security updates and may become incompatible with other things running on your machine.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda true but for the time being , we need to at least get the system working again.

Comment: @Serg: But I don't think that just stopping your kernel from updating is a good idea because then it will never receive important security updates which will lead the heightened possibility of a successful attack on the system.

Comment: That may be true for servers , which are constantly bombarded with botnets.  With desktop users - it can wait.