# No touchpad after 15.10 software update?

Tags: 15.10

I'm using a Toshiba Chromebook 2 and it's been going great until a couple days ago. Software update automatically ran and I installed the new software and after rebooting my touchpad doesn't work. I've looked around online and can't seem to find a solution. I don't believe my computer is detecting it at all. I've just reinstalled 15.10 without updating but would like to be able to update without fear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1549354

As stated in the bug report, the only current fix is to use the 4.2.0-27-generic kernel.

As explained [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version?lq=1), the easiest way to accomplish this is to hold down shift when booting and select the previous kernel in grub.

From my own personal experience, I found that holding down shift on my Toshiba Chromebook 2 isn't sufficient. Instead, I have to tap it repeatedly from the moment my computer is turned on in order to be sent to the grub menu. From there, it seems like my keyboard won't respond at the grub menu half the time, so I have to hold down the power button and repeat as necessary. I've successfully gone through this annoying cycle three times in testing, so I can say that it should work for you eventually.

(Alternatively, you could try changing the default grub selection as outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68547/editing-the-default-boot-item-in-grub-menu-a-definitive-answer), but that seems like an unnecessary hassle to me, as I assume the bug will get fixed eventually.)

If for some reason you don't still have the 4.2.0.27 kernel, you'll need to use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.2.0.27-generic linux-headers-4.2.0.27-generic
```

I'll change my answer when the bug gets fixed, but for now this is the best solution I've found.

(Note: By confirming that the bug affects you on [lauchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1549354), it should increase the chances of the bug getting addressed.)

Comment: Even when booting on the previous kernel my speakers and pad aren't recognized. It's ok for now as long as they fix it eventually. I confirmed in on launchpad, so hopefully it gets taken care of soon enough!

Comment: For the sound, I had to uninstall/reinstall the sound software by following the instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1316634) and then copying over the asound.state file again as outlined in step 5 [here](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/howto/install-ubuntu-on-the-toshiba-chromebook-2-in-5-steps/). After that sound worked on 4.2.0.27 and 4.2.0.30.