# Missing Windows XP in boot selection

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-xp, startupmanager

I'm actually having problems to boot back to my windows XP after setting the Ubuntu as default.I was using Ubuntu Startup Manager to change the default boot and also Windows XP setting on startup selection

At first I was following this thread [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader) but when i try to use the code

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ fgrep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg

menuentry "Ubuntu (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-13-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-13-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
```

Also I have been using this

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub


[sudo] password for administrator: 
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found Ubuntu on /dev/sda1
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-13-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-13-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
done
```

it seems that my windows XP is not in the list. And of course there is no XP in Startup Manager. So how can I back to Windows XP then?? I am really an absolute beginner on Ubuntu. Thanks! (and sorry if I didn't post this correctly. Please teach me how :p )

Comment: 1) Does Windows exist in a partition you can access from Ubuntu? 2) Can you boot into Windows XP?

Comment: 1) does that mean in the grub? no

Comment: 2)can't boot to windows XP at all

Comment: @saffiuddin Are you still experiencing this issue or have you moved on?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

1) Does Windows exist in a partition you can access from Ubuntu?

```
    *does that mean in the grub? no*
```

2)     Can you boot into Windows XP

```
*can't boot to windows XP at all*
```

IT means you may accidentally deleted windows boot files from c drive or erased windows partition ,use windows xp disk to recover it and [use this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) to recover ubuntu