# GRUB doesn't boot-up Windows as default even though I modified it using Start-up manager

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with Windows XP using GRUB 1.99.

I'm trying to make Windows XP boot up as default. However, when I tried using Start-up manager or edited the `/etc/default/grub` file, it still booted up Ubuntu.

I would like to try grub customizer but I'm not sure how to extract the file nor does my software center detect the repository when I add it.

Is there a way I can reorganize the options in grub or make Windows the default?

Comment: Did you run ` sudo update-grub` after modifying the `../default/grub` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub Customizer may work for you. To install Grub Customizer open a terminal window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy+paste the following lines:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

To start Grub Customizer click on the Applications launcher in the launcher panel (or press <kbd>Super</kbd>) and type `grub-customizer`. Then move the XP menu entry to the top of the list. When done save it and in a terminal window type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When done reboot to see if the changes work... good luck :)

Comment: Yea I managed to download and install grub-customizer and it works great, better than start-up mananger. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem.. glad it helped you! I had some grub problems in the past and the only working tool is grub customizer.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then type:

```
gksu nautilus
```

to edit `boot/grub/grub.cfg` and put the Windows menu entry first.

This needs to be done after each `update-grub`.

I'm not sure this is the best way.

See also:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/