# How do I change the the boot default from Ubuntu to Windows?

Tags: boot, default, boot-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

9 days ago I added Kubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) to Windows 7 on my computer. Since then  I have spent 12 hours plus trying to change the default grub selection from Ubuntu to Windows. I have gotten several different kind of advice, but none of them work.

I have changed to `GRUB_DEFAULT=5` and tried `GRUB-DEFAULT "Windows......"`   But no matter what, when I restart, Ubuntu is again the one that starts as default.

When I open the text editor it clearly now states "Windows....." as default, and it also showed 5, when 5 was set as default, only when I start up the computer.... it is always ubuntu, unless I stand at the computer and when the page with the boot options comes (GNU GRUB version 1.99 - 12ubuntu5) I click down to the sixth and last entry, my windows....

How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

After changing that configuration file, you need to run `sudo update-grub` in a Terminal to make it take effect.

Comment: Well, of course I did that.... each time. And I had advice from several Ubuntu "specialists". As it says "GRUB version 1.99", does that mean it is not Grub2 ?

Comment: Ok, you just didn't say you had so it wasn't clear. You should point out everything you've done in the question. GRUB version 1.99 is GRUB2.