# How do I set windows to boot as default in the boot loader? Unable to locate theme engine?

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot

Using this 
how-to [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)
I was able to get as far as here, however when I try to type in `gksu gedit /etc/default/grub` I am given 4 lines repeating the same message:

```
(gksu:2022): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the warning you must install the [gtk2-engines-pixbuf](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtk2-engines-pixbuf) package.

If that doesn't fix it you can use, for example, `nano`, is not as easy as gedit but you should be able to make the modifications the tutorial states.

Just type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

navigate with the arrows, save with `[Ctrl] + O`  and exit with `[Ctrl] + X`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need is Grub Customizer.  In the terminal, enter each of these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then open the Dash, find the program, and run it.  It will allow you to change the order in Grub, which is all you need to do since the first item boots by default.  Choose the Preferences icon, and a window will open: the first setting listed is "default entry"; use the dropdown next to it to choose your Windows boot, close the window and Grub Customizer, reboot and Windows should be listed first and will therefore be the default.

[image]