# How do I set Windows Boot Manager back to its default path?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have gone through quite a few questions on askubuntu similar to mine, like

[How do I set windows to boot as default in the boot loader? Unable to locate theme engine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106847/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-default-in-the-boot-loader-unable-to-locate-the)

[How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

but they do not provide the exact answer I am looking for. I have a dual booted PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr. I may wish to uninstall Ubuntu in future, and I have all except one step completely sorted out. I want to set Windows as my default Operating System, i.e. the PC should directly boot into Windows,  without displaying any menu.

While dual booting the PC, I had executed this command to get GRUB menu to load:

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

What command should I use to set the path back to its default value?

I do not want to use any additional tool. I do not want to uninstall Ubuntu right now. I want to achieve this using the command prompt from within Windows only.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, this is my first question on askubuntu. So if I have not followed any rules of posting, please let me know.

Comment: hey i want the reverse actually , i  have the windows OS set as default, instead  i want to show the menu whenever i restart, how should we do it? ( default OS as windows was set by the help center people, when i gave them my laptop for some issue,but now i want to set that to windows boot manager menu,how to do that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path
```

Will do it.