# Ubuntu HDD ALWAYS takes boot priority

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I have three hard drives installed on my machine, they are arranged chronologically in boot priority in my BIOS:

- 64 GB SSD **Windows Seven** | NFTS
- 120 GB HDD **Ubuntu 11.10** | DAT4
- 500 GB HDD **Storage For Both** | NFTS

What I am looking to do is make it so that GRUB will boot Windows 7 as my primary OS and always offer the option of Ubuntu. Currently, GRUB is on the MBR of the 120 GB HDD (Second in boot priority); and always boots Ubuntu by default. The only method I have found to getting Windows 7 to boot automatically is by **physically** detaching the HDD. I am running a custom built machine, 64-bit architecture LGA 1155 Mother Board; let me know if you need any other system information.

I am hoping to boot GRUB and have Windows 7 as the default option.

Comment: ... I think this is a duplicate of this! http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990

Comment: I had looked at that question @fossfreedom but my partitions we're not logical partitions on the same HDD - - they are actually individual Hard Drives and I didn't know if this was a hardware issue or a GRUB issue.

Comment: ...yep - it will work - however no worries.  Just keep in mind Oli's warning that you'll need to change your grub each time a kernel update is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Ubuntu run `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry`. Starting from zero, count down to the Windows entry, so if it's the eighth entry, you count to `7`.

Then edit grub:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` line to `GRUB_DEFAULT=X` where `X` is the number you counted to. <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and exit. Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And when you reboot that entry should be selected.

<sub>Note: This method didn't used to be recommended because the list would grow as more kernels were added in updates but now Ubuntu has a more fixed kernel list. If you manually add extra entries in the future you may find that you need to change which is set as the default.</sub>

Comment: Worked perfectly! I was rushing so fast; I accidentally changed `GRUB_DEFAULT` to 5 which was my Windows Recovery partition! Thank you!