# Ubuntu 12.04 Grub Error while changing default OS

Tags: grub2, 12.04, 64-bit

I would like report a problem which i faced after installing Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/11/how-to-change-default-os-at-boot-for.html

after following the instruction when i ran update-grub it asked me whether to generate menu.lst which is used older grub versions i told yes ..and the default os option still remained as the same.

Output of update-grub when i run is as follows

```
sudo update-grub 
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
Found GRUB 2: /boot/grub/core.img
Found kernel: /memtest86+.bin
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version did you update from? (and using what method) What version of Grub were you using?

Comment: @joe1983 If you want to add the output from `update-grub`, please do it by editing your question not by forcing it into a comment. I am not sure why you would want to add this though. What aspect of your problem will the output from `update-grub` illustrate?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are asking only for assistance in changing which OS GRUB boots by default on your system. This has been asked and answered previously. Please take a look at this question and its answers:
[**How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?**](https://askubuntu.com/q/52963/52923)

Setting `GRUB_DEFAULT=` to the numeric position in the GRUB menu of the OS you want to boot is a "less special" approach. This method can break if new entries are added to your GRUB menu.

Two other approaches you could use which might serve you better are:

1. Set `GRUB_DEFAULT=` to the title of the menu entry you want as your default. That method is described in [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/52990/52923) to the question above.
2. Set `GRUB_DEFAULT=` so the default is to boot the operating system you booted the last time (also referred to as the "saved method"). This is discussed in [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/83034/52923).

---

#### Please check the version of GRUB used on your computer

According to [**this section**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Grub#Recovering_GRUB) of the Ubuntu GRUB documentation, *you can check the current version installed on your system ... from the command line by opening a Terminal and entering the following:*

```
  grub-install -v
```

*Grub 2 should display a version number of 1.96 or later. Grub Legacy is version 0.97.*

Please also take a look at the version information displayed on your GRUB boot menu. It's pretty easy to find, but I provided an image to illustrate anyway. :-)

[image]

Another thing you could do which would help is to install the [**Boot-Repair tool**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and use it to `Create a Bootinfo summary`.

To do this you would first install the tool using `apt-get`. The terminal commands to do this are

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

1. When this completes (successfully), enter the command `boot-repair` to start the tool.
2. After a slight delay, `boot-repair` will prompt you to download the newest version. Since you just downloaded & installed the tool there is no need for this so answer `No`.
3. If `boot-repair` requests to install the `pastebinit` package, respond with `Yes`.
4. The tool will now scan your system and (eventually) display the window shown in the image below. For now just click on the box/button to `Create a Bootinfo summary`. This will collect information about your system's boot configuration, but *will not make any changes.*

   [image: Initial Boot-Repair Window]

   When the bootinfo summary has been created, `boot-repair` will display a message containing a URL like this: `http://paste.ubuntu.com/123456/`. Please add this URL to your question. The information this link points to will allow us to better understand how GRUB is set up on your computer.

Comment: still i could not change the default os and or os position as update-grub command is creating menu.lst instead of grub.cfg

Comment: ran this command and repaired it sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: You could also have used `sudo update-grub -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. My understanding is that the command `update-grub` is just (some sort of) alias for `grub-mkconfig`. Did you re-try just a simple `sudo update-grub` to ensure that it directs its output to `grub.cfg` and not `menu.lst` now? This is how the system will do it if it feels it needs to after installing an update.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems.

After my last couple of distribution upgrades, my grub didn't see the new kernel and update-grub didn't help. I needed to run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to let grub know that a new kernel existed.

I found out the reason after reading this article. I had grub2 installed on my disk, but only the grub package installed on the computer. Probably this is the reason why the dist-upgrade script (that probably uses update-grub) only updates the menu.lst and not grub.cfg.

I've just installed grub2 and now `update-grub` generates the `grub.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

I hope a reinstall of the grub can resolve your issue. Try booting the OS by inserting the Ubuntu CD and try the following command.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```