# Setting windows 7 as start up OS during Boot

Tags: server, dual-boot, windows-7, startup, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

How to set Windows 7 as default for booting? I am using Dual boot in my laptop. And how do i later shift to Ubuntu easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to follow:

1- To edit the grub file open terminal and type the following command :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You will got something like this :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=””

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo’
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640×480

# Uncomment if you don’t want GRUB to pass “root=UUID=xxx” parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entrys
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY=”true”
```

Now to change the boot order, you need to change the GRUB_DEFAULT Entry, for example you have  windows7 in the 3rd position and you want to set it as default, to do that set default to 3:  GRUB_DEFAULT=3

2- Now update Grub using the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And is done!

Comment: And how do i shift to Ubuntu if needed ? Can i shift without rebooting?

Comment: No. If you are in Windows you must reboot your computer and then choose Ubuntu to load.

Comment: oh k will try that.

Comment: You must consider, to virtualize Windows in Linux (Ex. With Virtualbox), to avoid rebooting to run Windows when you want, without rebooting.

Comment: Ya but i have seen my friends facing problems with speed and performance constraints. I will be using both almost equally... one of the projects is totally on Ubuntu and heavy data files and otherwise all my data is on Windows. :)