# How to change the default selection in GRUB2?

Tags: grub2, windows-7, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I have installed first Windows 7, then I installed Ubuntu 11.10.
Now the boot loader is GRUB and is showing a list of operating systems:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Windows 7

The default OS is Ubuntu, and if no action is detected after 10 seconds, the GRUB choose Ubuntu to start.
How can we configure the GRUB in order to chance the default OS?
I want Windows 7 to be the default OS and if no action is detected after 10 seconds, the OS that begins must be Windows 7.
Thanks