# change boot loader order

Tags: grub2, bootloader, boot-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the grub boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

I use windows as primary system. Last week, I installed newest Ubuntu, and I always accidentally boot in to Ubuntu when I want to boot into windows. Is there any way to change the order of this boot loader?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990