# How to change the default system of dual-boot using Wubi?

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot, wubi

I have both Windows XP and Ubuntu installed.
I want to set Ubuntu as my default system when boot the machine.
I don't want to press <kbd>Down</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> every time.

I am using Wubi.

---

#### Original `boot.ini`:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"
```

---

#### Modified `boot.ini`:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=C:\wubildr.mbr
[operating systems]
C:\wubildr.mbr = "Ubuntu"
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](http://askubuntu.com/q/52963/37006)

Comment: @BasharatSial No, that question is about the GRUB2 menu this with a standard Ubuntu installation. This question is about the Windows boot menu with a Wubi installation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click setting and select wubi as default operating system from drop-down menu. Click OK.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Warning: do not set the `Time to display operating systems` to zero when Ubuntu is the default OS. This will prevent Windows from booting. It can be easily fixed for Windows XP, but not on Windows Vista and 7 which requires a Windows repair CD. The minimum for the timeout should be 10 as even small numbers > 0 can cause problems.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using Wubi (saw `boot.ini`).

Use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).  It's a free program to modify the Windows Bootloader.

After you installed it, open it and go to the Edit boot menu Section.

Then tick the box beside the Ubuntu Entry under "Default".

Comment: easyBCD only works with vista or later(because it uses bcd as boot config.) not with XP(becasue xp uses boot.ini) except you have installed vista or seven along side.

Comment: It doesn't???  I never knew that.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the `grub.cfg` file.

In the Terminal:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You can change the `set default="0"` line. `0` is the first OS, `1` the second, and so forth.

Or you can change the menu entries.

When your system updates the kernel, you'll lose this GRUB configuration change and have to do it again.

Comment: The original poster here has a Wubi system, not a standard Ubuntu system. In a Wubi system, the boot menu that gives a choice between Windows and Ubuntu is the **Windows boot menu**, not the **GRUB2 boot menu**. So editing GRUB's configuration files won't help at all in this case. Also, graphical programs should be run with `gksu`/`gksudo`, not `sudo`, as [using `sudo` to run any nontrivial graphical program can (reversibly) break the program when you need to run it *not* as `root`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo). Also, for this you'd need `sudo update-grub` too.