# Dual-boot: Can't select Windows at boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader

I have a computer with 2 operating systems dual booted: One is **Windows 7** and the other is **Ubuntu**. My Ubuntu installation is installed within the Windows partition via wubi.exe.

I'm not using grubby, but windows 7's default bootloader. From within the windows settings i have set the time to choose the operating system to boot to zero, and as Ubuntu is at the top of the list, it boots automatically, not giving an option to load my windows 7 installation.

My problem is that I can not access my Windows 7 Operating System. It is essential to my work, so I am unable to remove this partition. Could someone give me a clue as to what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I found [izx's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/148097/31938) here to be your best option.

If you aren't too comfortable editing these files there is an app called Grub Customizer which can modify a lot of grub settings. You can read more [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/grub-customizer-30-released.html) - definitely worth a try.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the timeout in Windows BCD to a value >0

You can proceed either by

1) Running Windows 7 StartUp Repair which will reset timeout to 30 secs.

2) Edit BCD timeout -

run Windows 7 install/repair CD/DVD/USB and select repair->command prompt
**bcdedit /timeout 30**  - to reset to default 30 secs

Answer (score 0):

While it is the question if the inability to boot to windows is a disadvantage, you can edit the

*/etc/default/grub*

file
and change the line

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

after that you run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Don't you have to also run `sudo update-grub` to put that into effect?

Comment: im not using grub, my ubuntu is installed within windows via the aplication thing from the website, i forget what its called

Comment: If you do not use grub. Then you use the windows bootloader... This makes things a little different. I guess windows has a  config file for that. I rememeber that pressing F8 was doing something, i think safe mode. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Then you have installed Ubuntu INSIDE Windows (via the Wubi installer). In this case, the correct solution is to change the timeout in the Windows bootloader. See snayob's answer.