# time out in ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, boot, startup

When I switch on my computer,my computer goes black for ten seconds and starts to boot.
This happens because ,I tweaked in start up and session to time-out for 10 seconds.But when I tried to change time out to 0 second,I does not happen and be in same time-out 10 seconds.

Can I change the time-out seconds to null through command ?

Is there any other way to change time-out seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand how you changed the time-out but it's possible to change grub time-out editing `/etc/default/grub`.

On terminal type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, it will ask for your password. Look for the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` and change to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`. Save the file and run `sudo update-grub` on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

After you change it to 0, are you updating grub?

sudo update-grub

More info here: [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)