# Chosing OS on Boot with broken enter key

Tags: boot, dual-boot, keyboard

Summary: enter button unavailable when choosing OS (either ubuntu or windows7)

Today I have installed ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows7.  When BIOS asks which OS to run I am unable to select other than the default - which is selected after 10s timeout. (if I use the arrow keys the timeout no longer counts down).

I changed the default OS that boots after grub-timeout to my regular windows 7... as described here:

[How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry).

However I'm wondering if there's any way I can select ubuntu by other than with the 'enter' button.  This button happens to be the ONLY button that is not working and I have to plug in another keyboard via USB.

NOTE: On windows I have mapped another key to act as the 'enter' button, and hoping to do the same within ubuntu - if you are able to help me there as well, it would be appreciated but not my main concern.

If you can help me as to what I could possibly do, I give you 5 hundred PROPS :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the Left Arrow key. I just tested it one of on my Ubuntu machines, and it worked like a charm, without me even needing to configure or change anything.[image]

EDIT: I meant the Right Arrow, not the left one.

Comment: wow, that was awesome!  it was actually the right arrow key on mine.  thank you very much for that help.  nice emoticon by the way :P