# OS selection option in grub goes in a flash

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, flash

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and windows 7 in dual boot.recently a problem started to occur,sometimes when I switch on my laptop the grub screen to select the OS comes and goes in a flash wwithout giving me any time to switch OS.Apart from that whenever this happens the splash screen of ubuntu flickers with alternate flash screen and some text screen and keeps flickering without booting in.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the application Grub Bootloader (available in the Ubuntu Software Centre.  This will allow you to set  how long the computer waits before booting into the selected OS, as well as choosing which OS is highlighted by default at startup

Comment: thanks for the reply.but my problem is not about the grub_timeout.If it was,it would happen every time I am logging in to ubuntu.but this problem doesn't occur all the time.I found a jumpstart for my system to boot to desktop.but I don't want to do this all the time(and it won't work).I use to press and hold esc key as soon as the boot process starts so the screen goes black and the esc equivalent (text like: [^[^...)is displayed then I press enter so my system won't get into the flicker loop.I think this may help you to diagnose the problem and give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can [adjust grub's timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry) by editing `/etc/default/grub`. You should set the `GRUB_TIMEOUT`to the number of seconds you want grub to show. After you edit the file you should run the command `sudo update-grub`. When you reboot the changes should take effect.