# I've installed Dual Boot, Windows 8 and Ubuntu, how I can select to boot Win8 on boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

Well, now every time I boot my PC, its run ubuntu, and I need to press F8 to select Windows 8, the problem is its not only who use this PC, and I need to Windows 8 run without pressing any key or selecting it. Its possible?

Thank you, sorry for my bad english, I'm Latin and 16 old.

Comment: This question might help you to change the default boot OS: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have grub, see nitstorm's answer to install grub-customizer:

[How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Once installed, you'd probably want to move the "Windows 8" option to the top.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! note that you can also directly share the answer's link, and not the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar enough with Grub and Grub2 bootloader to help.... I do know there are settings that change the default OS being booted first....

Another option is to try Easy Bcd which is an after market bootloader that is installed from windows. It is quite easy to use and the download and instructions can be found at:

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

this will get you up and running for now...

It does not remove Grub but works with it so you can just uninstall Easy BCD when you figure out the problem you have with Grub....

I just left mine running with Easy BCD because I am lazy....

Oh get the free version on the website if you are only using it for your personal computer...

You only need to buy it if you use it commercially....

Comment: You are more than welcome... Glad that it worked for you... Dual booting can be a pain when you are just learning how to set up and use a new operating system...