# is there an Xubutu (XFCE) equivalent to gnome-session-quit

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I see a neat [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380854/can-i-change-the-grub-default-choice-from-windows) by Steve Dee to a question I have, but it's specific to Gnome in that it uses gnome-session-quit to log out the current user.  I use Xubuntu, and thus XFCE.  Is there an equivalent?

To the extent it matters, I'm using a variety of versions, always the one native to a supported LTS Xubuntu.

Comment: Well it depends what version you have. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1244964/edit) your question and add the version of your distro and - to make it easier for us - which xfce version you are currently using

Comment: What about using `xfce4-session-logout`?

Comment: I'm using a variety of versions, always the one that comes with my Xubuntu, and that  may be any of the LTS versions currently supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the latest XFCE 4.14 there is a command:

xfce4-session-logout

```
Usage:
  xfce4-session-logout [OPTION…] 

Help Options:
  -?, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -l, --logout             Log out without displaying the logout dialog
  -h, --halt               Halt without displaying the logout dialog
  -r, --reboot             Reboot without displaying the logout dialog
  -s, --suspend            Suspend without displaying the logout dialog
  -i, --hibernate          Hibernate without displaying the logout dialog
  -b, --hybrid-sleep       Hybrid Sleep without displaying the logout dialog
  -u, --switch-user        Switch user without displaying the logout dialog
  -f, --fast               Log out quickly; don't save the session
  -V, --version            Print version information and exit
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

Is it that what you're looking for?

Comment: That worked on my main laptop running Xubunu 18.04.4.  Yippee!

Comment: it also appears to be present in a much older 16.04 partition that I have not tested.  Thanks again.

Comment: cool, I wasn't sure so I thought I'd better ask. That is what makes XFCE rock. Far more configurable as GNOME.