# There was no /etc/default/grub file, so how come my system was able to boot?

Tags: grub2

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. I wanted to change the GRUB timeout by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file. But there was no such file in my system.

On startup the GRUB menu is displayed and I'm not experiencing any boot problems. If this file was so important for booting, why am I nit experiencing any boot problems?

Comment: If you do not facing any problems... then may I ask; why is that you need to edit the grub file??

Comment: to set the grub timeout.

Comment: The one I found is for 12.04 but still this may help you when you try with `sudo` .. http://askubuntu.com/a/148097/179042

Comment: it won't works,there was no such file.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken 13.04 uses GRUB ver. 2... It was in /boot/grub/menu.lst and has been replaced by /boot/grub/grub.cfg.. you may have to try `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: In 13.10 the files are in /etc/grub.d/  You can directly edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg but your edits can be overwritten by an update

Comment: i didn't see `GRUB_TIMEOUT` line on that file.

Comment: In my **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** I found the last occurrence of `set timeout=10` and changed it to `set timeout=-1` as i wanted the menu to wait for me to make a selection. Works for me but sometimes an update causes me to have to re-edit.

Comment: but there was no such line in my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

Comment: Do you have this line in **/boot/grub/grub.cfg** `### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###`? if so, you could try adding `set timeout=-1` just ahead of that line. If you want a short time out use 2 or 5 instead of -1.  That is where timeout is in my .cfg file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reinstall the package and hope for the best:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub-pc
```

Actually the file is not critical for the boot, just to configure the boot when you execute `sudo update-grub`. If the file doesn't exist, then all values are default ones, like you didn't set them up.

Comment: We can also set the grub timeout like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406229/there-was-no-etc-default-grub-file/407311?noredirect=1#comment523553_406229)?

Comment: "Do you have this line in /boot/grub/grub.cfg" he's presuming you have the file. If you don't have it (as your question suggest) it will do nothing.

Comment: yes i have that file and also have the line `set timeout=-1` within curly braces.

Comment: "I'm trying to change the grub timeout by editing the /etc/default/grub file.But there was no such file in my pc."???? You say in your question that you don't have the file, now you say that you have the file, please decide.

Comment: i don't have `/etc/default/grub` file but i had `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj don't modify `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` by hand. There's a very big notice in the second line that read **# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE**.

Comment: @AvinashRaj How to get back to default modified `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` I don't know which lines I changed.

Comment: @KasiyA grub-mkconfig file automatically re-creates that file so any changes made will be restored.

Answer (score 5):

just copy example from `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really only want to know "why this works", the answer is that LiveCD Ubuntu that you used for installation had this **unimportant for boot** file `\etc\default\grub.cfg`, so created yours **important for boot** `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` using it.