# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 on same HDD as Windows 7, Windows 7 won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu on the same hard drive as my Windows 7 (different partition of course)

Edit: Windows wouldn't boot and after trying to fix mbr with Windows recovery console Windows isn't recognized in boot anymore.

I really don't want to re-install Windows. How can I make Windows boot up again?

---

As for how I installed Ubuntu:

1. I had Windows 7 already installed.
2. Used Windows tools from within windows to shrink partition to free up space for Ubuntu
3. Rebooted into Ubuntu from CD.
4. Used Ubuntu installation disk tools *Something else* option. to create new partition for Ubuntu from unallocated space.
5. Installation was done and then Windows stopped booting.

---

I managed to get to Windows recovery console by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> but now I'm not sure how to fix the Windows boot record.

I tried using fixmbr, bootrec, bootsect /nt60 all /mbr.

Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Added some more information regarding what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Hirens Boot CD (http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)

The CD has lots of tools to fix boot problems.

One significant is that you can boot from a selected partition and by this you can test if your Windows partitions still works.

If it still works I would recommend you to try fixing GRUB.
GRUB is the first thing that start when the computer boot when Ubuntu is installed.

There is 2 solutions here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=24113

You can also try to fix the master boot record (MBR) with tools on Hirens CD.

I prefer to fix GRUB as I have had success doing so and you will get a nice booting menu where you can select between Ubuntu and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you boot, does the GRUB menu give you a selection of which OS to boot to? If not, when you're in Ubuntu, you need to modify the timeout in the GRUB config file.
Here are good instructions to do that.
[How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

You can also fix the Windows MBR by booting from a Windows 7 cd, and selecting "repair installation"(or something like that)

But you do need GRUB if you intend to keep a dual boot system.