# I want to boot directly to my UBUNTU OS without chosing on GRUB menu

Tags: boot

Firstly, I have my Vista OS, then I wanna use UBUNTU only, so I install Ubuntu succesfull replace to Vista OS. after that I can't boot to Ubuntu but I still see Boot WIndows menu with ERROR. 
I tried to use boot-repair by USB with LIVE UBUNTU and now I am typing this ASK by Ubuntu. But i had the problem that I have to chose GRUB menu with WINDOWS 7 (it show windows 7 i/o Vista lol) and Ubuntu. So i want to boot to UBUNTU not via this GRub menu directly.

This is my [paste.ubuntu.com/7934349/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7934349/) so pls help me to fix it with as much details as much help for me.

Comment: You could install grub customiser and change how long grub shows for and the boot order.

Comment: Do you want to remove Windows completely and install Ubuntu? Or do you want to have a dual boot system, with both Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: tks you, i want to remove completely Windows boot (I already delete the phycical drive Windows and Install Ubuntu on this)

Comment: Why not just reinstall Ubuntu all over again, because you shouldn't have any NTFS records left after installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Initial Default
>
> 1. If no other operating system is detected GRUB 2 will boot straight
>      into the default operating system and no menu will be displayed.
> 2. If another operating system is detected the GRUB 2 menu will
>      display.
>
> #### Timed Display
>
> 3. The menu is displayed for a predetermined number of seconds. The
>      default entry is highlighted and other selections may be made by the
>      user until the timeout expires. The default timeout is 2 seconds.
>      The timer continues until any key is pressed or the highlighted
>      entry is selected by pressing ENTER.
> 4. If no user input is made GRUB 2 boots the default entry at the end
>      of the timeout period.
> 5. Once a key has been pressed the timeout is deactivated and the user
>      must make a selection manually.
> 6. The default entry is determined by the **GRUB_DEFAULT=** setting in
>      `/etc/default/grub`; the first "menuentry" has a value of "0".
>
> #### Hidden
>
> 1. Normal Hidden Operations Enabled:
>
>    1. No menu entries are displayed. The splash screen, if configured,will be displayed.
>    2. The time the screen remains blank but available for display is
>         determined by a setting in `/etc/default/grub` (**GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT**)
>    3. GRUB 2 can display a countdown timer to provide visual feedback on
>         the time remaining until the default selection is chosen. The
>         timeout setting is enabled in `/etc/default/grub`
>         (**GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET**)
>    4. The user may display the menu by pressing any key.
>
>       1. Once the menu displays, the GRUB_TIMEOUT counter begins. Pressing any key stops the countdown.
>
>          1. If no key is pressed by the end of the timeout the default entry determined by settings in /etc/default/grub will be
>               selected.
> 2. Hidden Menu Operations Not Expected (Abnormal):
>
>    1. The user may be able to display the menu in one or more of the following ways:
>
>       1. Holding down the SHIFT key early in the boot process until the menu displays.
>
>          1. GRUB 2 searches for a depressed SHIFT key signal during boot. If the key is pressed or GRUB 2 cannot determine the
>               status of the key, the menu is displayed.
>       2. Pressing the ESC key during a 3 second window as GRUB 2 runs

You can follow the steps in here to change default boot entry to Ubuntu and to change default timeout:
 [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

Comment: paste.ubuntu.com/7934349/  pls check this one and guide me to boot to Ubuntu

Comment: If manually editing grub config seems difficult, I'd recommend what @Tim suggests. Install grub customizer gui application and you could easily delete, modify boot entries with just a few clicks.