# Grub boot menu not available after installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on MSI GE 60

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, grub2, msi

I installed Windows 8.1 on an MSI GE60 laptop; then proceeded to partition it using GParted (resized the NTFS partitions) and installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS in the free space I created /dev/sda8.

When I run bootinfoscript after logging into Ubuntu, the output looks as follows (see below, excuse the rather long cut-paste). The problem I am having is that I do not have a grub boot menu that allows me to choose which OS to boot into (I used to be able to do this with 8.04 Hardy Heron and 10.04 without much trouble on an older laptop). It boots into Ubuntu by default. The only way I am able to boot into Windows is by hitting the delete key when the MSI logo appears, entering BIOS, and changing the value of the option for `Boot Mode Select` option from `Legacy` to `UEFI`.

Appreciate if anyone has any ideas or suggestions to help me get the grub boot menu option which gives me both OS choices to boot into, so that I don't have to go into the BIOS everytime I want to work in Windows.

Thanks in advance for your time & ideas.

My settings in /etc/default/grub looks as follows:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

My bootinfoscript RESULTS.txt output:

```
                      Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    1563601216 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     1,230,847     1,228,800 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda2       1,230,848     1,845,247       614,400 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3       1,845,248     2,107,391       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda4       2,107,392   485,371,844   483,264,453 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5     485,371,845   777,770,909   292,399,065 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda6     777,770,910   807,105,599    29,334,690 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda7     807,106,560   838,746,111    31,639,552 Swap partition (Linux)
/dev/sda8     838,746,112 1,953,523,455 1,114,777,344 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        AE0E04680E042BC1                       ntfs       WinRE tools
/dev/sda2        7406-CB53                              vfat       SYSTEM
/dev/sda4        96C60823C6080669                       ntfs       OS_Install
/dev/sda5        C80809AC08099B18                       ntfs       DATA
/dev/sda6        D60C0BD60C0BB113                       ntfs       BIOS_RVY
/dev/sda7        aa389ccf-6371-4229-b25c-9ffcbc08f58a   swap       
/dev/sda8        467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221   ext3       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda8        /                        ext3       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda8/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt8'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt8 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt8  467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt8'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt8 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt8  467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt8'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt8 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt8  467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt8'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt8 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt8  467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt8'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt8 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt8  467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt8'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt8 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt8  467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda8/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=467dd323-cfdc-47e0-b151-f1abfaeca221 /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=aa389ccf-6371-4229-b25c-9ffcbc08f58a none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda8: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 08 5e 1b  |.X.MSDOS5.0...^.|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 c8 12 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 60 09 00 51 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |.`..Q...........|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 53 cb 06 74 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..)S..tNO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 44 69  |..............Di|
000001b0  73 6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72  ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73  |sk error...Press|
000001c0  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  20 74 6f 20 72 65 73 74  | any key to rest|
000001d0  61 72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |art.............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-Wx1Jigrb/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

**Edit**:

Result of sudo update-grub after commenting the lines suggested by amantethy:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Comment: Your Windows is installed in UEFI boot mode and Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. The two modes are not compatible and you can only dual boot from UEFI/BIOS menu and may have to turn on or off UEFI or BIOS boot settings. Grub can only dual boot other installs in same boot mode as you booted grub. You can use Boot-Repair to convert a BIOS install of Ubuntu to UEFI if drive is gpt partitioned which Windows requires if it is in UEFI mode. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system AND: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: thanks @oldfred: Will give this a try and reply back (likely tomorrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the suggestion from @oldfred:

Your Windows is installed in UEFI boot mode and Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. The two modes are not compatible and you can only dual boot from UEFI/BIOS menu and may have to turn on or off UEFI or BIOS boot settings. Grub can only dual boot other installs in same boot mode as you booted grub. You can use Boot-Repair to convert a BIOS install of Ubuntu to UEFI if drive is gpt partitioned which Windows requires if it is in UEFI mode

But this didn't work likely because boot repair isn't up-to-date for 14.04.1 LTS (got some error in the end). So I ended up doing the following:

Formatted the partition containing my 14.04.1 LTS and re-installed after rebooting from BIOS this time keeping UEFI mode active and fast boot disabled. This worked without any issues and presented the dual boot option from the get-go.

Answer (score 4):

The answer can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry). Your GRUB is set to hide the OS selection menu on boot.

Basically, what you'll need to do is make the following change:

- Add a # before the two "hidden" lines.

Open up a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) and then enter in the following command: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. Edit the file so that,

`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`

becomes

`#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

`#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`

Save the file (`ctrl+x` and then `y` to save) and then run `sudo update-grub`.

When you reboot you should see the OS Selection Menu.

Comment: @amathethy: Thanks, this brought up the grub menu and I do see Ubuntu and memtest in the options, but my Windows OS is not one of the options, which is what I really wanted.

Comment: Even after running the `update-grub` command? That usually scans the drive and builds a new list of all your OS's. Can you post the output that `update-grub` generates?

Comment: Yes, even after running the update-grub. I posted the result of that command as an edit to my original post (bottom).

Comment: I just reread your post and then read the comment @oldfred left for you. I'm pretty sure he's right. I originally missed the part where you mention that you can boot into Win by changing to UEFI mode. Using boot-repair to convert your grub from BIOS to EFI should fix things.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the GRUB menu by hitting `Shift` key while your system boots.