# Ubuntu grub in dual boot

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I have a Windows 7/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual boot and I've been using it with the Windows boot loader for a while. After a while, when I choose Ubuntu in the Windows boot loader I am redirected to the Ubuntu grub, where I can choose again between Windows and Ubuntu.
How can I remove the grub?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grub Customizer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134) or [edit grub manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry) to disable grub menu from showing up and make Ubuntu default choice. That way you will no longer face a choice again and will directly boot to Ubuntu. I don't think you will want to really "remove" grub because you cannot boot Ubuntu without it.

If Ubuntu is the first choice in grub menu, while editing grub manually just changing `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` should be enough.

So,

- start Terminal and type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- change timeout to 0 in opening text editor
- type `sudo update-grub`

you should be done.

If Ubuntu is not appearing as first choice in your grub menu, you also need to change that.

Comment: I tried in both the ways (grub customizer and edit grab manually) and even with TIMEOUT=0 it doesn't start automatically. What should I do?