# MPTCP installation and configuration on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel

I'm trying to install MPTCP (Multipath TCP) on my Ubuntu but I have a problem :

I follow instructions under this link : http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/AptRepository

I have no problem on first steps but, after restarting my pc and follow instruction for the routing configuration , I restart again my pc and in third step, when I'm trying to configure MPTCP [Configure MPTCP](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/ConfigureMPTCP)

I have a problem, it's asked to me to get the version of MPTCP, do (in a running system):
  dmesg | grep MPTCP

I excecute this command and nothing is show in result.

Result of uname -a
Linux MPTCP 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x-86_64 x86-64 GNU/Linux

When I am trying to execute the commande for the last version of MPTCP, 
sysctrl -w net.mptcp.mptcp_enable=1 
Ireceive as answer sysctrl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/mptcp/mptcp_enable: No suche file or directory.

When I check in command line, there is no folder /proc/sys/net/mptcp

Thanks for help.

Regards, djaneu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago. Make sure you select the MPTCP kernel on boot.

Answer (score 0):

While Loading the kernel Ubuntu does not load the mptcp in your case

A solution is to change the grub2 configuration in `/etc/default/grub` file options to show the Ubuntu kernel options

Documentation can be found at [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

A helpful tool is the Grub Customizer. It also allows you to set the mptcp kernel as default.

More details can be found at [How to Configure the Linux Grub2 Boot Menu the Easy Way](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/)