# dualboot ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop.

I want Ubuntu to be the default and auto starting and windows to boot only when selected.

Is that possible and how do I get it to work ?

Comment: There are alot of topics like that, check out shit link - 
[How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry][1]
[1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry

Answer (score 0):

**Graphical Method**

1. Install StartUp-Manager
2. Go to Boot Options >> Default Operating System
3. Select your Linux version. Change the timeout number to a lower number if you want a speedier boot sequence.

**Terminal Method**

1. Type `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry`
   . Note your Linux entry number (remember that entries start at 0. Thus if Linux is the 5th entry then your entry number is 4 for example).
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` by changing `GRUB_DEFAULT` from 0 to your noted Linux entry number.
3. Type `sudo update-grub` to update your changes to the bootloader.

Good luck!

Source:

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-change-the-boot-order-of-a-dual-boot-linux-pc/