# How to get an Starting Double Boot Menu (Linux / Windows)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I performed the creation of a new partition into the internal HDD of my desktop computer.

The original 3 partitions of this HDD contain the Linux Ubuntu Studio 15.10 operating system, the swap partition and my personal data. The new partition contains Windows 7 Ultimate, now.

The Ubuntu, Swap and Windows partitions are primary partitions. My data partition is an extended partition.

My problem is when I put the computer ON: I can not to choose, I don't have a dual boot menu at the computer starting moment and, now, I just can enter into Windows 7.

What's wrong here?

What's happened with Ubuntu Studio?

How can I build the Dual Boot Menu?

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!!!!!!!

Juan

Comment: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be looking for something like this: 
[How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

The preferred way to install dual boot is install Windows first, then Linux. That way you get the grub dual boot menu. Otherwise Windows overwrites the master boot record. Glad you figured it out though!

Answer (score 0):

The only one way I discovered to perform this was... To re-install the whole system from the Installation DVD (I discovered the wheel! hahaha!).

I used the re-install option, trying to avoid to loose installed software.

BUT... Just a bad new: I lost some installed software, I had. Yes, but all of them can be easily re-installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Now I can enter to Ubuntu or Windows 7. Both systems work so fine!!!

The only one thing I could to claim is about the waiting time of the Starting Dual Boot Menu, Can we change it? How?

Greetings & Blessings from  Chile!!!!!!!

Juan