# Where did GRUB go?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I recently installed WIndows ten alongside Ubuntu 14.04. After doing this, I used a LiveUSB to use Boot Repair and restore GRUB. After rebooting, GRUB appeared, and when I selected the Windows option, Windows booted. However, after shutting down and restarting with the intention of booting Ubuntu, Ubuntu booted without the GRUB menu appearing. How can I get the GRUB menu to appear every time I start my PC?

Comment: Windows updates may reset it to first in UEFI boot order. What does this show? `sudo efibootmgr -v` And can you still boot Ubuntu with one time boot key often f10 or f12?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Grub Timeout is set to zero.
Have a look at this link:
[How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)
Maybe it helps you.

Comment: I didn't have to do anything, the next time I booted, GRUB appeared, and it has ever since. Weird.