# Issue with ubuntu/linux boot and grub

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb

I have a windows box that I wanted to trial Ubuntu with. So using two usb sticks I used one stick as a Ubuntu installer and installed it onto the other stick.

I changed the bois to boot from usb first, so when the usb stick is plugged in it boots into Ubuntu.

This is working great, infact the Ubuntu boot gives me the option to boot into windows or Ubuntu - which is an unexpected bonus.

However, the problem is when I shutdown and reboot (or restart) the PC goes into some strange (to me) command line like this:

`grub:`

I can power the PC down and then back up and it still goes into this `grub` CLI. The only way I have found to get around this is to boot into bois, do nothing (since the settings are correct) and then save+exit and then it boots into the Ubuntu boot-menu as normal.

Can anyone explain what is going on and how to avoid this grub CLI?

**Update**

I have done some searching around and have found out (I think) what grub is.... it seems to be Ubuntu/Linux's boot program.

So I think I need to configure my "grub" to boot normally into Ubuntu every time (or maybe used last saved value)... maybe like [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

However for me my system boots directly onto the grub command line and does not provide the boot menu.... I am not sure what that means in terms of how to configure grub (see my earlier question for details there - the first link).

So I am still stuck, but I have a vague idea what I need to do, any pointers would be great.

**update-2**

I have tried the link haddy provided... it seemed to be going well, until I discovered that when I do ls I can only see one drive (the hdd and not the usb):

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt7) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2)
(hd0,gpt1)
```

Unfortunatly I can't copy/paste.... but if I do `ls (hd0` and tab it out I get:

```
grub> ls (hd0[tab]
possible partitions are:

Device hd0: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512Kb - total size 488386584KiB
    Partition hd0,gpt1: Filesystem type fat - Label 'SYSTEM', UUID....
    Partition hd0,gpt1: No known file system detected...
            :
    Partition hd0,gpt7: No known file system detected...
```

So it looks like grub is not seeing my USB drive... which is odd since it should be booting off that drive. If I go into BIOS and exit it (with no changes) then it boots fine... its strange.

**update-3**

ok, so I realised that when I remove my usb stick it still boots into grub.... so this must mean it has been installed onto the windows HDD. So I have followed a list of instructions from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/6) and I can always boot into ubuntu from grub, but the option to boot into windows has gone! :o

not sure what to do now :(

Comment: Have you already tried this? https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux Maybe something went wrong with installing and it can be fixed by a reinstall.

Comment: @MarkKirby ok, then please leave this question - I will go and copy/paste the two questions into one question here and delete them off...

Comment: @MarkKirby - ok done, that should clear up the mess I made :p

Comment: OK I will remove my vote and leave this comment for others to see you removed the SU questions. You can clean up your comments to me too, if you like.

Comment: @haddy - what happened to your answer? well, when I get home ad test this out I will come back and update this comment. if it works I'll let you know so you can post back your answer : )

Comment: @code_fodder The answer was converted to a comment, it did not meet quality guidelines. It is the first comment below this question.

Comment: «the PC goes into some strange (to me) command line» Does this happen with the Ubuntu USB key inserted or without it?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Its both... I originally thought it was only with the usb in, but I was wrong. There is something installed on the windows HDD that has taken over the boot. I have just mounted the windows OS on my linux and backed up all my files.... I think its time to install ubuntu over windows :p

Comment: Installing Ubuntu over Windows is a great idea. If you still want direct access to Windows, though, you can boot into your Ubuntu USB drive, chainload (boot) Windows from it and use EasyBCD to recover Windows' bootloader.

Comment: @EduardoCola ...err.... not the way I am installing it :o...lol :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Comment: @DavidFoerster + kronies: wrong, I have already installed ubuntu to usb and its working fine (the installation that is)... my problem is a boot/grub issue. I think the question is clear enough and so does the person who answered. There is only one question mark in my question and it is in this line: `Can anyone explain what is going on and how to avoid this grub CLI?` - I think that is a pretty clear question, do you? - all the rest of the text are updates to the post with further info... what more can a guy do before the "duplicate-police" come knocking??... anyway, mehhhhh, I'm done here : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the problem is when I shutdown and reboot (or restart) the PC goes into some strange (to me) command line like this:
>
> ```
> grub:
> ```

If this happens when your Ubuntu USB key is disconnected, it means you overwrote the boot record of your Windows system with a different MBR which is looking for GRUB.

You should restore the boot record of your hard drive using the Windows installation disc (or recovery disc created through the Windows interface), while the USB key is not connected. But this outside the scope of this website.

Comment: I think you are right about that! - but... I am moving to ubuntu cuz windowz sucks ass (especially since win8 - and even more especially since win10 was stealth installed and we lost all our settings) and the only reason I ever use it is for games or if I have to at work :p