# GNU Grub boot time out command

Tags: grub2, timeout, gnu

1/ I am not a Ubuntu user.
2/ I am using dual boot Windows 10 and Remix OS 3.0 on my Dell xps 9350. On the dual boot option with GNU Grub there is the time counting down, which is 30seconds - too long for me.
3/ So anyone please time me how to adjust this time out, for example, to 5 seconds.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

Comment: Unfortunately your distribution is no (official) flavour of Ubuntu and off topic here. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE]. There are also a StackExchange sites specifically for [ElementaryOS.SE] (beta) and [Fedora](//ask.fedoraproject.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to abort the countdown and start the highlighted option immediately.

From within Ubuntu, you can change the countdown timer value by opening the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then typing:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

to edit the configuration file.

Search for the line:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
```

Then save the configuration file and exit the editor.

Next you need to compile the configuration file with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then type `exit` to close the terminal.

When you boot again there will be a 5 second countdown instead of 30 seconds.

Comment: sorry but I dont have the Ubuntu, I just have Remix OS 3.0 and the Windows 10. That's why I ask :((

Can I do these command when hitting C during boot time ?