# dual boot - boot automatically into windows 10

Tags: grub2

so i bought Hard Disk Drive and Solid State Drive, and i installed windows 10 on Solid State Drive, and Ubuntu 16.10 on shrink Hard Disk Drive. so every time i power on the PC it doesn't show me the grub, and its booting to windows 10 automatically. and when i want to open Ubuntu i need to get to the BIOS and choose "boot load" on Hard Disk Drive. 
My opinion is that maybe Ubuntu didn't find the windows because it was on another drive ... and Ubuntu searched only in the Hard Disk for Operating System. Thanks for help.

---

i did what you said... changed boot priority to HDD and run `sudo update-grub`
but it didn't find windows.

```
 Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-22-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after installing win 10?

Comment: Did you install both in UEFI or both in BIOS boot mode? May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the boot order specified in your BIOS. Your SSD is booting ahead of your HDD.

Because `grub` isn't appearing at boot, it means that your HDD isn't being loaded first. In addition, once you do correct your boot-order, run `sudo update-grub` to allow Ubuntu to autodetect your Windows installation.