# How to have grub auto-detect another Linux installation?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, btrfs, grub-legacy

I have just installed Xubuntu 17.10, and I have noticed that grub did not detect my previous Manjaro installation (which is still intact in another partition, I checked).

How do I get grub to add Manjaro as booting option? 
Please provide easy-to-follow instructions, as I am a newbie.

Thanks

EDIT 1: I have already tried using sudo update-grub and sudo update-grub2, rebooting after using each one, and it made no difference at all. 
Moreover, I want to point out that at boot time I do not see the grub menu -- the screen is blank for a few seconds, and then Xubuntu boots normally.

Edit 2: I don't know if this matters, but the filesystem of my Manjaro OS partition is btrfs

Comment: Did you have the partition mounted as grub has run? Maybe mounting it and rerun `update-grub`will do it then?

Comment: Yes, I tried that already, but it makes no difference. Moreover, for some unknown reason when I boot I do not see any grub menu at all -- the screen is blank and after a few seconds Xubuntu boots.

Comment: Read [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/a/148097/723193). `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` will allow you  to change some of grubs defaults. Comment out the grub-hidden lines by prefixing them with `#`. Run `sudo update-grub`, and reboot to see if grub has a menu entry for all os's.

Comment: do you have btrfs-progs installed?

Comment: yes, it is installed

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that the checks update-grub2 does is unable to read a BTRFS partition. In theory they should work if you've got it mounted, but grub is supposed to run before any such file system drivers are loaded so it might make sense that it didn't pick up this particular partition.

I've had some similar issues with XFS formatted partitions too. It seems grub only like FAT/EXT/NTFS. For other stuff I've always had to manually edit the grub menu.

BTW, I prefer using Grub Customizer to editing the grub config file in a text editor. Though it's not available in the normal repositories, I have to add a ppa from launchpad to install this tool: https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer

Comment: Does grub support btrfs or not?!? Should this not be documented?

Comment: Grub itself doesn't "have" to. All it's doing is pointing the boot process to a specific sector on the drive. It's the automated editing of the settings for these sectors (i.e. the update-grub) program which is likely not reading the correct one.