# Dual boot won't boot (Win10 and Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

Whenever I boot my computer, I do not get any boot-menu to choose OS. It neither boots until I keep pressing ENTER (return). When it finally boots, it boots into UBUNTU and not windows. When earlier I used to get boot-menu, UBUNTU was the first option so presumably on pressing ENTER it is booting in UBUNTU.

Here is output from boot-repair.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kNw2DfHKMk/

The boot repair doesn't recognize Windows 10 installation in sda4:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FWSJ4zH7NT/

Comment: My grub file is fine. I used to get dual boot till like yesterday. Something happened overnight when I kept my PC on and slept.

Comment: Yep, thats what I meant when I said my GRUB file is fine.

Comment: Boot-Repair is saying Windows is hibernated, or fast start up is on. You have to directly boot Windows and turn off fast start up. Windows 10 is not really good for dual booting in BIOS mode as now you have to use your Windows repair disk or possibly Boot-Repair to temporarily install Windows boot loader, boot & repair Windows and then restore grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Answer (score 0):

Press/hold `Shift` after the BIOS screen, you should see the GRUB boot menu.

If Windows is displayed on this screen you can select it from there.

You can also press the boot selection function key, usually `F12` to get your UEFI bios to display the available boot options.

If everything works correctly with both of the above options you can use this [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry) to select a different timeout option on the GRUB screen so that it allows you enough time to make a selection without having to time either the `F12` or `Shift` key presses at every future boot.