# How to go straight to Windows 10 without GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 19.04

This is the thing: I have a **secondary laptop** with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04 and I use GRUB to select every time which OS to load. This is great for me...BUT my little brother plays a lot of games on this laptop frequently. So now, I just want Windows 10 to load directly without losing Ubuntu because sometimes I need it.
How can I do this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry has all you need.

Comment: If your little brother is smart enough to play Windows 10 games, can't he simply arrow down to select Windows 10 on menu and press `Enter`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yeah...but I know my brother XD. It´s better to do it like I'm asking. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You can try changing Boot priority. Windows boot manager to load first instead of grub.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the **Grub Customizer** program you have installed with Grub itself.

You can find it in your apps