# Expand filesystem from command line - sda1-5 already in use

Tags: partitioning, disk, lvm

I have a headless Ubuntu server install inside a VM, running on Hyper-V using `lvm`. I have full access to the VM, but no access to the Hyper-V environment (so can't boot with a LiveCD).

I need to expand my filesystem as I've already eexpanded my physical disk at the virtual level, but am having issues as sda1-5 are already in use.

Is there anything I can do to make use of the space assigned to the server but not used?

My mounted volumes:

```
root@SRVLIN01:~# mount | grep --regexp "^//[0-9]" --regexp "^/dev"
/dev/mapper/SRVLIN01--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl,stripe=4)
root@SRVLIN01:~#
```

My logical volumes:

```
root@SRVLIN01:~# lvdisplay --maps
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/SRVLIN01-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                SRVLIN01-vg
  LV UUID                0GWjvA-b7H7-nLqX-TOtV-VNdR-QFT3-nhucpd
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time SRVLIN01, 2017-05-04 09:40:59 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                117.51 GiB
  Current LE             30083
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 14722:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda5
    Physical extents    0 to 14722

  Logical extents 14723 to 14725:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda5
    Physical extents    15234 to 15236

  Logical extents 14726 to 30082:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda4
    Physical extents    0 to 15356


  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/SRVLIN01-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                SRVLIN01-vg
  LV UUID                KFFa26-3GQY-Fbc3-QIU2-BdRe-h7Af-s16fKE
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time SRVLIN01, 2017-05-04 09:40:59 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             511
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Segments ---
  Logical extents 0 to 510:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda5
    Physical extents    14723 to 15233
```

My physical volumes:

```
root@SRVLIN01:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               SRVLIN01-vg
  PV Size               59.52 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              15237
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          15237
  PV UUID               ljFlcO-kfjd-bx2d-74DJ-BY3S-zoKM-dBmfiJ

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda4
  VG Name               SRVLIN01-vg
  PV Size               60.00 GiB / not usable 0
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              15360
  Free PE               3
  Allocated PE          15357
  PV UUID               WY90Op-u2Bz-nVTf-D2ed-q4Zu-lEgW-e4ZLfY
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** `sda3`-`sda5` are not mounted.  What is preventing you from shrinking `sda4` and adding its space to `sda5`?  **0:-)**

Comment: Thanks :-)

The honest answer is because I don't know how to ..I'm not even sure how you've determined that sda3-5 aren't mounted?

Comment: I can't see sda3-5 in `df -h`, so assuming they're not mounted. and `sda2` is just an extended partition. Please [edit] your question and provide the output to `mount | grep --regexp "^//[0-9]" --regexp "^/dev"`, then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: I added that data to the original post, thanks

Comment: Oh, I get it what you're trying to do.  Answer coming up.

Comment: Thank  you for the acceptance! Favour returned and question upvoted.  (Under VMWare I would have been able to tell you that you can mount an ISO through vCenter and boot from there, but I don't know Hyper-V, so sorry about that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running in a Virtual Machine (VM) using `lvm`: Logical Volume Manager and the only unused physical partition not under its control is /dev/sda3 which is just 1MB, so that won't help you much.

`lvm` is really great at handling multiple kinds of storage and can combine multiple disks into one Physical Volume (PV) which can then be (re-)assigned  as you need them.

However, you have allocated all (except 1MB) of your physical disks, so now you only have these choices:

1. **add another disk**

   - Don't expand existing mounted disks that you cannot dismount to expand in the future.
   - never assign 100% of your disks so you can extend your existing Physical Volumes on the free space you now have with your new disk.
2. *Alternatively, mount a `gparted` live ISO from within grub if your Hyper-V environment gives you access to that.*

   - **Take a full snapshot of your VM!!!**
   - Download the [gparted live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) iso
   - copy it in `/opt/LiveISOs`

     ```
     sudo mkdir /opt/LiveISOs
     sudo cp ~/Downloads/gparted-live-1.0.0-3-amd64.iso /opt/LiveISOs
     ```
   - edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to include the following at the end:

     ```
     menuentry "GParted Live ISO" {
       set ISOFile="/opt/Live-ISOs/gparted-live-1.0.0-3-amd64.iso"
       loopback loop ($root)$ISOFile
       linuxefi (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live components config findiso=$ISOFile ip=frommedia toram=filesystem.squashfs union=overlay username=user
       initrdefi (loop)/live/initrd.img
     }
     ```
   - set grub's timeout parameter to [anything but 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)
   - update the `grub` config:

     ```
     sudo update-grub2
     ```
   - Reboot to grub
   - Take menu option <kbd>GParted Live ISO</kbd>

   Voilà: a *virtual* USB key has been inserted in your VM *virtually* and you can now shrink / expand partitions off-line using gparted or using `lvm` utilities from the command line!

<sub>#2 above *will not work* if the only thing you have is ssh access to your VM...</sub>

Comment: The server is on a virtual host. Within that we have expanded the size of the disk, however we need to expand the partition to make use of that:

[Disk /dev/sda: 160 GiB, 171798691840 bytes, 335544320 sectors]

That's where I'm stuck as all the advice I read online talks about either using a LiveCD or creating a new partition in the unused space, which I can't do as I've used all five already.

Comment: @c-hri-s All intermediate comments deleted so that the Q & A can stand all by themselves for the next person that runs into the same issue as you.