# How to make grub menu appear instead of booting directly to windows 10

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot

- HP Envy X360 with SecureBoot/UEFI boot loader
- I ran boot-repair from USB stick
- Tried to change boot order in BIOS (I see both Windows and ubuntu but cannot select and save ubuntu)
- With F9 at boot I can see the ubuntu menu, also can successfully boot to either W10 or ubuntu 18.04
- I can also see and reboot to grub menu from Windows with super-r, ms-settings:recovery, Restart Now and choosing boot from External, choose ubuntu

So I am guessing this is an HP question as well as ubuntu one. I will check their discussion groups and if I get an answer, will report back here. I may also try clearing all secure boot keys from BIOS to see if that allows me to select grub as first in boot order.

TIA for any advice or insight HP owners may have!
--Alex

Comment: Take a look at this answer, perhaps it can help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry#answer-148097 boot into Ubuntu and I think you just need the right `GRUB_TIMEOUT` setting in `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: Not quite ... I don't think the TIMEOUT setting has any bearing on the boot order, which I believe is the root issue here. Secure Boot settings are more likely the culprit. Thanks for the thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

The hotkeys are F5 and F6 in HP BIOS to change Boot order. However, to save the new boot order you need F10, which wasn't mentioned in the onscreen help guide. Problem fixed!