# Get rid of Grub timer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I tried to get rid of the timer, so grub immediated loads the OS.

This is the file that I edited with

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

#GRUB_DEFAULT=0 *original code*
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after editing the file? Dual boot? Ubuntu version? Please add information via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1233659/edit) to your question.

Comment: Might be answered here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before and wanted to add a special background for GRUB menu too and I found nice way to solve it. Just follow my steps:

1. Install Grub Customizer by opening your terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and running:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
   ```
2. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, search for "grub" and open Grub Customizer.

   [image: Open Grub Customizer]
3. Go to *General settings*, then check *Boot default entry after* and change the timer as you want. Here, my timer is `1` seconds.

   [image: Grub Customizer settings]
4. Click on *Save*, then reboot your system and, congrats, it's working.

**Not Important :**

1. If you want to change background, font size, color or anything related to appearance, then Go to *Appearance settings*. Here is how my GRUB looks:

   [image: Customized GRUB]
2. Let's assume that you have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu in your PC and want to always start Windows as default. Then go to *List configuration* and adjust the OS order:

   [image: Grub customizer List Configuration]

Hope that helps you. Good luck.