# When I start the pc GNU grub bootloader page loads

Tags: boot, lubuntu, windows-10, bootloader, grubrescue

I installed Ubuntu on a pendrive and now every time I on my PC (even if the pendrive isn't connected) grub bootloader page loads instead of windows. If I have to on windows I have to press F12 continuously when the Dell screen comes. After that I get options to selects Ubuntu or Windows. How can I make the pc to load Windows directly and load Ubuntu only when pendrive is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have done the following: While installing the "pen drive" you selected your main hard disk as target for grub. So the "boot manager" thinks there are two operating systems available. Only change (without reinstalling windows) is to insert your stick again, start Ubuntu and change your "grub" configuration.

For this you need to to do (in Ubuntu): Edit the contents of `/etc default/grub` like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry):
You'll need to know where your windows is located..
the line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` should be altered by you.
After saving that file it its necessary to execute (in a terminal): `sudo update-grub`. Next time Grub (which is your bootmanager now) will start windows by default.

Comment: Is there any risk to my laptop or Windows OS if I leave it like that (use F12 to select windows everytime)?

Comment: No, there is no risk besides using Windows ;-)