# Change main Ubuntu OS kernel version as default

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have been reading main questions on the form about changing the Ubuntu kernel by editing the `GRUB_DEFAULT` variable to point to your desired kernel version in submenu. However, I was unable to find whether it would be possible to change the Ubuntu kernel in the main menu of grub i.e. replacing where the Ubuntu OS in the menu points towards? So I do not have to go to the sub menu of the grub every time I want to boot.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

Comment: Unless you really need to change the kernel, and if you are not an expert user, please don't mess up with the kernel.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I really need to change the kernel because the newer kernel did not recognize my extra ssd slot.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I have seen many question about changing the default option but none for replacing the ubuntu option in the main menu for using a different kernel.