# Gnu-Grub appearred, can't make it go away

Tags: dual-boot

Recently I temporarily had to use F10 to choose between two drives at startup, one Windoze 10, and one Ubuntu 20.04.6.  A few days later I had my mechanical switching re-set up, and dispensed with the F10 at boot.

BUT now, without my making any changes, either before or after the use of F10 to select, a screen called GNU-Grub appears, which I wait for until it disappears and normal Ubuntu boot takes place.

Neither Windoze nor any other OS except Ubuntu is on this hard drive, and never has been.

How do I make the system revert to a normal boot WITHOUT the GNU-Grub screen?

Thanks !!!

Comment: If UEFI system, your Ubuntu/grub boot is probably in the ESP also used by Windows on the first drive. Do you have an ESP on Ubuntu drive? Ubuntu with 20.04 defaulted the install of grub to first drive, whatever UEFI/BIOS said was first drive, but usually the ESP on Windows drive. You can create an ESP on Ubuntu drive, change fstab entry of ESP to UUID of new FAT32 ( with boot,esp flags) partition and reinstall grub. `sudo grub-install` That uses all  defaults and fstab entry for where to install grub.  Some systems, do not like drive switches, not sure what advantage that gives.

Answer (score 0):

GNU GRUB[1] is a boot loader used to load Linux(including Ubuntu). While in GRUB menu, you can always hit enter to choose selected OS right away. Or you can update GRUB configuration with the value of `GRUB_TIMEOUT` set to `0` [2][3]. But keep in mind after changing GRUB configuration, GRUB will boot default choice immediately.

To edit grub configuration file run

```
sudo su
vim /etc/default/grub # replace vim with your text editor
```

then set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`. Then save the file and run

```
update-grub # this will update the changes for GRUB
```

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB

[2] [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)

[3] https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration