# How do I dual-boot Windows by default?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, dual-boot, default

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I am new to Ubuntu, but have used Macs and PCs for years. I am referencing the idea of how on a Mac, and you install Boot Camp, how Mac automatically runs by default, and you can run Windows by holding down the option key.

> I will be mainly using Windows, and I don't want to have to choose
>   windows or wait for it to time out by default. I can then press a
>   secondary key, or something similar to boot Ubuntu.

How do I accomplish this?